# Facebook permissions confusion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to retrieve the user id and name using the iO SDK. As I understand, no additional authorization is needed to get these parameters.

Therefore I do this:

```
FBRequest *userIDRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name" 
                                              andDelegate:self];
```

And then deal with the data. However when I do this I get an error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
```

The only thing I could find regarding this error was a lack of user permissions, but as I said above these items should be gotten for free. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestWithGraph path already have the URL in the method call. You'd only have to add the graph path to the method:

```
FBRequest *userIDRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams: params andDelegate:self];
```

Just make sure you fill the params appropriately.

Comment: Params is a dictionary, is there documentation for the specific key value repairs needed? I couldn't find it on the developers.fb.com site

Comment: It's the same ones that you would use in Graph API. In your example you want to set "fields" as "id, name" so set "fields" as the key and "id,name" as the value of that params dictionary. This sample iOS project might help you: https://github.com/fbsamples/Wishlist/blob/master/iOS/Wishlist/Wishlist/HomeViewController.m (starting from line 156 they are calling Graph API)